# Checkbox rounded with custom check image

Tags: android, checkbox

I would like to make a custom checkbox like that when it's checked :
[image: checkbox]

And like that when it's unchecked :
[image]

For that, I have to change the color of the background with #00bf72, I have to put some rounded border and change the drawable of the checkbox image.

I don't know how can I do that. I tried a lot of things but it's not working.

Answer (score -2):

create checkbox_states.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
          <solid android:color="#5ec639" />
          <stroke
              android:width="2dip"
              android:color="#00000000" />
          <padding
              android:bottom="4dp"
              android:left="4dp"
              android:right="4dp"
              android:top="4dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
          <solid android:color="#5ec639" />
          <stroke
              android:width="2dip"
              android:color="#00000000" />
          <padding
              android:bottom="4dp"
              android:left="4dp"
              android:right="4dp"
              android:top="4dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>
    </selector>
```

In check box background you can use

```
android:background="@drawable/checkbox_states"
```